# How to adjust outer labels for nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to plot graph with some outer labels.

I found that there some helpful attributes - `xlabel`,`taillabel`,`headlabel` but the result still looks weird.

MCVE

```
digraph {
forcelabels=true;
node [shape=point,style=filled;label="",height=0.2];
y3[color=black;xlabel=<"y3 (2)">];x3[color=gray;xlabel=<"x3 [0.25]">];
y2[color=black;xlabel=<"y2 (3)">];x2[color=gray;xlabel=<"x2 [0.3]">];
y1[color=black;xlabel=<"y1 (2)">];x1[color=gray;xlabel=<"x1 [0.1]">];
y5[color=black;xlabel=<"y5 (4)">];x5[color=gray;xlabel=<"x5 [0.15]">];
x4[color=gray;xlabel=<"x4 [0.2]">];
y3->y2[dir=none;taillabel = 0.75];
y2->y1[dir=none;taillabel = 0.45];
y1->y5[dir=none;taillabel = 0.35];
y3->x3[dir=none];
y2->x2[dir=none];
y1->x1[dir=none];
y5->x5[dir=none];
y5->x4[dir=none];
}
```

it looks like

[image]

As you can see, conformity between labels and nodes not always obvious.

So, the Q is - is there any way to change location of labels ?

Comment: Can you let us know what you want - your request / complaint is not very concrete...

Comment: @vaettchen I just want to get something similiar to [this](https://imgur.com/a/VdH1l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer to your question as it still does not look great and takes a lot of manual adjustment, but I post it anyway: I spent quite some time fiddling around, and there may be some ideas that could be helpful for your actual context:

```
digraph 
{
    forcelabels = TRUE;
    splines = FALSE;

    // nodes
    node[ shape = point, style = filled, color = gray, label = "", height = 0.2 ];
    x3[ xlabel = <"x3 [0.25]"> ];
    x2[ xlabel = <"x2 [0.3]"> ];
    x1[ xlabel = <"x1 [0.1]"> ];
    x5[ xlabel = <"x5 [0.15]"> ];
    x4;
    node[ color = black ];
    y3, y2, y1, y5;
    node[ shape = plaintext, fillcolor = white ];   
    y_3[ label = "y3 (2)" ];
    y_2[ label = "y2 (3)" ];
    y_1[ label = "y1 (2)" ];
    y_5[ label = "y5 (4)" ];

    // edges
    edge[ dir = none ];
    y3:se -> y2[ label = "  0.75" ];
    y2:se -> y1[ label = "  0.45" ];
    y1:se -> y5[ label = "  0.35" ];
    y3 -> x3;
    y2 -> x2;
    y1 -> x1;
    y5 -> x5;
    y5 -> x4[ headlabel = <"x4 [0.2]"> ];
    edge[ style = invis ];
    { rank = same; y3 -> y_3 }
    { rank = same; y2 -> y_2 }
    { rank = same; y1 -> y_1 }      
    { rank = same; y5 -> y_5 }  
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice. Thank you, let me think a bit before I accept your answer